# What does the Facebook API mean when it says "user is not a confirmed user"

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have an app that uses the Graph API to access our users' information from Facebook. For some users, our requests fail. When I check these specific users' access tokens with FB's Access Token Debugger, I receive the following error:

Error validating access token: Sessions for the user are not allowed because the user is not a confirmed user.

Note that this is not the same error we receive when a token has expired, password changed, etc.

All the FB docs say about this error is: "The user needs to log in at https://www.facebook.com or https://m.facebook.com to correct an issue."

Some searching online implies this error might be caused when a user deactivates Facebook, which is supported by the fact that their profiles return a "Sorry, this content isn't available right now." But I'd like to have some confirmation.

Does this error mean someone has deactivated Facebook? Left FB entirely? Something else?

Comment: It may be that the user has signed up to Facebook, but has not verified their account, most likely via mobile phone number, so FB perhaps doesn't trust that it is a legitimate user. Best way to check would be to create a new FB account, don't verify it, use your app and see if you get the same error. That'd be my suggestion.

Comment: @baylee is it the case the Patrick Lambe described?

Comment: I didn't confirm, but based on the number of people affected and the age of their accounts, I think it's more likely people who deactivated their FB accounts

Comment: Has anyone gotten confirmation?

Comment: Does anyone knows the root cause of this problem ?

Comment: "Note that this is not the same error we receive when a token has expired, password changed, etc."

@baylee what error do you receive when a token has expired?